# What are the benefits of having non-decayed weapons?

Tags: zelda-tears-of-the-kingdom

We learn from the captain that weapons found underground are not decayed.

[image: some fused weapons]

*Same weapons, one decayed, one not*

I assume that means those weapons will have better stats and durability so will last longer than those that are decayed.

Is this assumption correct? What are the other benefits of non-decayed vs decayed weapons?

You can't sell weapons in general so it can't be monetary.

Comment: [Kleric](https://www.youtube.com/@KlericYT) will probably post durability values soon-ish, like for [BOTW](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=McgsHEwlNG8) (link in description).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Multiple sources seem to indicate that decayed weapons do in fact have lower stats:

From [*Attack of the Fanboy*](https://attackofthefanboy.com/guides/how-to-get-clean-weapons-in-zelda-tears-of-the-kingdom/):

> Clean weapons have a unique icon next to their names to denote their pristine status. They’ll also have slightly higher stats than their decayed counterparts. Plus, they won’t break as easily...

From [Gamepur](https://www.gamepur.com/guides/tears-of-the-kingdom-where-to-get-clean-weapons):

> Decayed swords, spears, and axes have blue spots, making them look tainted. Besides the rotten appearance, decayed weapons also tend to have lower stats.

This seems to be the only actual drawback to them.  You can fuse other weapons or items to them to improve their stats, but most sites seem to recommend against that.  Thus the benefits to them compared to their "clean" counterparts *is none*.